# Emailing multiple recipients, each showing up as the "To:"

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am making an application in which I want to send email to multiple recipients.

When sending an email I want the user's email to show up as the "To:" address for every user, without the users being able to see each others addresses.

I cannot use "BCC:" because it will not show to address.

Right now sending these emails using a loop. I want to know if there is any other solution available where I do not have to use a loop to do this.

Like if I have 100 or 10000 email address to whom I want to send email the page will take a lot of time
I am using .net only
Please donot suggest about sending from SQL SERVER

Comment: Since you're denying all the answers posted, we REALLY need to see some code to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Either show your own email address as recipient and use the bcc approach for all real recipients or you have to send single emails in a loop.

Comment: My answer contains the only two options you have: If you don't want to use a loop, there is no way to include different email addresses as recipient.

Comment: if this is ur answer then I am already implementing it may be there is some other way someone can suggest

Answer (score 0):

I think the loop is the only way